# asp.net invoke "target" pseudo css class

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have an html accordion that is essentially a bunch of  tags with some css
A section then gets styled as being active through the :target pseudo class.
problem being, any server controls that cause a postback, then we loose the the selected section.

I was thinking to try add something so make my  run on the server, and inject a class name, but I am not sure how to tell it to be active.
I have also tried setting the focus

example:

```
        <div class="accordion vertical">  
          <section id="Section1">  
              <h2><a href="#Section1">LALALA LALa</a></h2>  
               <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"  />

          </section>  

          <section id="Section2">  
              <h2><a href="#Section2">ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZz</a></h2>  
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>  
          </section>
</div>
```

css:

```
.accordion {   
    width:300px;
    height:650px;   
    overflow:hidden;   
    color:#474747;   
    background:#fff;
    padding:10px; 
    text-align: center;
}  

.accordion section{
    float:left;  
    overflow:hidden; 
    color:#333;   
    cursor:pointer;   
    margin:3px;   
}

.accordion section:hover {  
    background:#ececec;  
}

.accordion section p { 
    width: 92%;   
    display:none;
    text-align: left;
}  

.accordion section:after{  
    position:relative;  
    font-size:24px;  
    color:#000;  
    font-weight:bold;  
 }  

.accordion section:nth-child(1):after{ content:'1'; }  
.accordion section:nth-child(2):after{ content:'2'; }  
.accordion section:nth-child(3):after{ content:'3'; }  
.accordion section:nth-child(4):after{ content:'4'; }  
.accordion section:nth-child(5):after{ content:'5'; }  

.accordion section:target {
    width: 92%;
    background: #f3fbe5;    
    padding:10px;  
}  

.accordion section:target:hover {   
    background: #f3fbe5; 
}  

.accordion section:target h2 {  
    width:100%;
    color:#fff;
}  

.accordion section:target h2 a{  
    color:#333;   
    padding:0;
    font-weight: 700;  
}  

.accordion section:target p { 
    width: 90%; 
    display:block; 
}  

.accordion section h2 a{ 
    padding:15px 10px;  
    display:block;   
    font-size:16px;   
    font-weight:normal;  
    color:#000;   
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family: MyraidProReg;
}  

.vertical section{   
    width:100%;
    height:40px;  
    -webkit-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;  
    -moz-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;  
    -o-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;  
    transition:height 0.2s ease-out;  
}  

/*Set height of the slide*/  
.vertical :target{   
    height:250px;   
    width:97%;  
}

.vertical section h2 {   
    position:relative;
}  
/*Set position of the number on the slide*/  
.vertical section:after{   
    top:-60px;  
    left:250px;  
}  
.vertical section:target:after{   
    left:-9999px;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this one. just putting down my solution here incase someone needs it (or I get hit by a car and develop amnesia and need to resolve this in the future - hello future crudler).

Ok the problem isnt linked to either the accordian, or the controls underneath. The root cause is that a postback doesnt preserve the hashtag location.

So you can either do some funny stuff with the form's action, or catch the post back (on each control) and then set a startupscript as such

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "anchor", "#Section2", true);
```

or if you are using a update panel to be nice and ajaxy (named pnl in my case)

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(pnl, pnl.GetType(), "anchor", "#Section2", true);
```

you can then do some sneaky things like put the # name as one of your html tags, strip it out on the post back and make your method more generic